# Is it possible to use Travis CI with Flutter to build only?

Tags: dart, flutter, travis-ci

I wanna study Travis Ci with flutter, but normally it is used for testing. But, I have no time to run how to test applications and only want to use it for the build.

Is it useless for only building goals or worthy?

Comment: iOS or Android? You can use it to build but it's a good idea to ensure tests pass before that anyway.

Comment: I suppose only Android platform and I want to test, but it takes much time to learn about testing technique. Isn't it?

Comment: I see. Android shouldn't be a problem. Seems iOS is supported as well (haven't tried myself https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/)